# Angular routing overrides href behavior utilized by tab and collapse panel plugins

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm using twitter-bootstrap for tabs and collapse panels. Both of these plugins work off of overriding hrefs. Sometimes - not consistently, the routeprovider will override the tab/collapse behavior and try to use it as a route.

I would love a workaround for this issue, but have also added it as an issue on
[github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1557)

A couple of suggestions of workaround implementations:

1. If .otherwise is not provided - do not touch any route that is not
   specifically configured.
2. add .ignore('path') to the routeProvider as a configuration option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a workaround, instead of using
`href="#targetDivId"`, Twitter Bootstrap allows `data-target="#targetDivId"` as an attribute, which solved my issue.

Here's the thread describing the issue: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1557#issuecomment-10303715)

Comment: Also add 

      .. data-target="#collapse" class="pointer">...

css:
     .pointer {
         cursor: pointer;
      }

Comment: Don't forget to include # symbol.
data-target="#targetDivId"

Comment: By the way, this also works for circumventing Backbone routes as originally, the page gets routed to a 404 whenever you click the panel's header.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scope to connect between the tabs and the pane, bypassing the route:

```
<div class="tabbable">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li ng-class="{'active':currentTab == 'Tab1'}">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" ng-click="currentTab = 'Tab1'">Tab1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li ng-class="{'active':currentTab== 'Tab2'}">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" ng-click="currentTab = 'Tab2'">Tab2</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active':currentTab == 'Tab1'}" id="Tab1">
                                        <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active':currentTab == 'Tab2'}" id="Tab2"> 
                                        <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: How do I make a tab active by default?

Comment: You'd add the class 'active' to the div.